# Null values in the generated classes

Tags: java, apache-axis, axis

I'm using Apache Axis2 v 1.5.6 and Axis1 v1.2.1

I'm using those to generate Java objects from a web service .wsdl.

I am then accessing the values from those objects. For example

```
recevedObject.getFooInfo().getFooInfoGroup1().getTheValue().
```

should I be performing null checking in cases like these. Or does Axis make sure that none of the Object fields are null? Its fine if `getTheValue()` returns `null`. but I don't want to be getting Null pointer exceptions because `getFooInfo()` returns `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, Axis helps to convert SOAP(XML) response into object structure and this SOAP elements are defined using XSD.
Hence, getting NPE depends on your XML element declaration in the XSD which is going to be source for the response validation. E.g. if getFooInfo element which represents lets say FooInfo element in XML/SOAP response message and if that's nil-able, there are chances you may get NPE while getFooInfo() and if its non nil-able then you will not get NPE.

Answer (score 0):

If you should not receive null values for fooInfo in your XML and that is defined in your XSD, you should activate the XML validation w.r.t. the XSD.

For instance, you can use it with CXF through the *schema-validation-enabled* option. There is probably something similar in AXIS, I guess.